# Why await operator doesn't work in NUnit TearDown?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, async-await

I have API integration tests in **nUnit**. When I added execute async method in `[TearDown]` I saw that await operator doesn't work ...

```
[TearDown]
public async void TearDownAsync()
{
  var response = await service.GetTasksAsync();

  if (response.Count > 0)
  {

  }
}
```

In this sample method `GetTasksAsync()` is executed but doesn't wait for result. When I change it to use `Wait()` it's ok.

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
  var response = service.GetTasksAsync();
  service.Wait();

  if (response.Result.Count > 0)
  {

  }
}
```

I think the problem is in the`[TearDown]`. Method is executed but thread is ended prematurely. In `[Test]` method everything is ok. Is it a bug in [TearDown] or I'm using it improperly?

Comment: Define your method as `async Task`, not `async void`.

Comment: what for you call GetTasksAsync?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Doesn't work. "ignored invalid signature for setup or teardown method setup"

Comment: the answer is [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-framework/issues/60)

Comment: @Mariusz: async teardowns and setups are not supported in Nunit: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-framework/issues/60. I suggest making the calls blocking or switching to MStest.